# explode and trim numbers into array from a string in PHP

Tags: php

This is my original string :

```
$license_str = "<strong>Code#1: </strong>11516331226428373002<br><strong>Code#2: </strong>11512231686337183002<br>";
```

First I tried to strip html tags so :

```
$license_str = strip_tags($license_str );
```

output would be :

```
    Code#1: 11512231686337183002Code#2: 11516331686337183002
```

Then I ran preg_split to extract two license codes :

```
 $license_code = preg_split("@: @",$license_str,Null,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

output is wrong :

```
        array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "Code#1"
  [1]=>
  string(26) "11512231686337183002Code#2"
  [2]=>
  string(20) "11512231686337183002"
}
```

It must return two array value with two license number

Is there a better way to do this?

PS. : Code#1 and Code#2 is dynamic and we could have #3 or any other number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the string by pattern '/Code#(\d+):/'

like.

```
<?php

$license_str = "<strong>Code#1: </strong>11516331226428373002<br><strong>Code#2: </strong>11512231686337183002<br><strong>Code#3: </strong>11512231686337183008<strong>Code#4: </strong>11512231686337183007<br>";

$license_str = strip_tags($license_str );
//split by code#number: like, code#1:, code#2:, code#3: etc.
$result = preg_split("/Code#(\d+):/", $license_str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/I5E7E)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to replace the `Code#1`, `Code#2`, ... with a `#`, and then split the string on that character.

```
$license_str = "<strong>Code#1: </strong>11516331226428373002<br><strong>Code#2: </strong>11512231686337183002<br>";
$license_str = strip_tags($license_str );
$license_str = preg_replace('/Code#[0-9]+: /', '#', $license_str);
$license_code = explode("#",$license_str);
var_dump($license_code);
```

Alternatively, the following will apply a single regex on the HTML that extracts the codes, however, it depends on the codes always being between a `</strong>` and a `<br>` tag:

```
$matches = array();
$license_str = "<strong>Code#1: </strong>11516331226428373002<br><strong>Code#2: </strong>11512231686337183003<br>";
$license_code = preg_match_all('/<\/strong>(\d*)<br>/', $license_str, $matches);
$matches = $matches[1] ?? false;
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: Code#1 and #2 is dynamic and we don't know how many would be there

Comment: You need to rethink this. Your solution won't work.

Comment: I've made it work with an arbitrary number of codes now.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of HTML tags instead of stripping them, like this:

```
<?php
$license_str = "<strong>Code#1: </strong>11516331226428373002<br><strong>Code#2: </strong>11512231686337183002<br>";

if(preg_match_all('#<strong>([^\<]+)\s</strong>([^\<]+)<br>#', $license_str, $matches)){
    $license_code = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
    print_r($license_code);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't recommended to parse HTML using string manipulation because of the many edge cases inherent in HTML compliant code. You should rather use an HTML parser.

One approach is to use PHP's [DOM extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php), like this:

```php
$license_str = "<strong>Code#1: </strong>11516331226428373002<br><strong>Code#2: </strong>11512231686337183002<br>";

$license_codes = [];

$dom = DOMDocument::loadHTML($license_str);
$domlist = (new DOMXPath($dom))->evaluate('//strong[contains(.,"Code#")]/following-sibling::text()');
foreach ($domlist as $domtext) {
  $license_codes[] = $domtext->textContent;
}

/*
$license_codes = array (
  0 => '11516331226428373002',
  1 => '11512231686337183002',
);
*/
```

This above code will extract the string that follows any HTML `<strong>` tag containing the text "Code#".

You can try it out [here](https://repl.it/repls/DoubleCluelessRoutes).